# how do I fix a bash error when removing characters from string?

Tags: bash

This is not a homework assignment.  I am new to bash and trying to gather some data from our logging.

I am reading lines from a file.  All of the lines look like this:

`[info] 1 - 12-04 15:33:37.542 : Finished createWalletRandom, total time 9898ms`

I need to parse out the milliseconds (which I will get min, max, average).  I can get `9898ms` and I need to get rid of the `ms` for the math to work.

Trying this line below, doesn't change anything:

```
MILLI_SECONDS=${RAW_MILLI_SECONDS%??}
```

And trying this below, generates an error `get_wallet_times.sh: line 23: -2: substring expression < 0`:

```
MILLI_SECONDS=${RAW_MILLI_SECONDS::-2}
```

Here is my code:

```
while read ONE_LINE;
do
    echo $ONE_LINE
    RAW_MILLI_SECONDS="$(cut -d' ' -f13 <<<"$ONE_LINE")"
    echo $RAW_MILLI_SECONDS
    MILLI_SECONDS=${RAW_MILLI_SECONDS::-2}
    MILLI_SECONDS=${RAW_MILLI_SECONDS%??}
    echo ${MILLI_SECONDS}
    LINE_COUNT=$((LINE_COUNT+1))
    FILE_SUM=$((FILE_SUM+MILLI_SECONDS))
done < logfile.txt
```

This is on macOS, in case its a bash issue specific to mac. Please let me know if there is anything thing else you need.

Thnx
Matt

Comment: Does `MILLI_SECONDS=${RAW_MILLI_SECONDS/ms/}` work?

Comment: yes it does.  thank you.  if you will, please make that an answer :)

Comment: Maybe there are additional characters (spaces?) after `ms` so `%??` removes two of them. What is the output of `echo "${RAW_MILLI_SECONDS}X"`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I wondered that as well.  I used a line `echo "|${RAW_MILLI_SECONDS}|"` and got back `|9898ms|`.  So I don't think theres anything trailing, unless I did that wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure if there are differences to the MacOS implementation of `bash`, but you could try RegExp-based string modification as in

```
MILLI_SECONDS=${RAW_MILLI_SECONDS/ms/}
```

which will replace the pattern `ms` by the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to parse the entire file

```
awk '
    /ms$/ { ms += $NF }
    END { printf "Total %ld ms from %d record(s)\n", ms, NR }
' <logfile.txt
```

The first line matches against `ms` as the last two characters of a line and sums the numeric value of the corresponding field. The `END` line reports the totals.