# how do I fix invalid arithmetic operator using bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am parsing a log file. My goal is gather avg, min, max of time from it.

I am able to parse the milliseconds from each line. When I try to do math on it, I get the error: `17607 + 0 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is " + 0 ")`

Lines from the file look like this:

```
./test_1_iws_1.txt:[info] 1   - 12-05 22:18:13.436 :    Finished createWalletRandom, total time 17607ms 
./test_1_iws_1.txt:[info] 1   - 12-05 22:18:19.504 :    Finished createWalletRandom, total time 21978ms 
./test_1_iws_1.txt:[info] 1   - 12-05 22:18:23.419 :    Finished createWalletRandom, total time 25815ms
```

and my code is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
LINE_COUNT=0
FILE_SLOWEST=1
FILE_LONGEST=1
FILE_SUM=0
while read ONE_LINE;
do
    RAW_MILLI_SECONDS="$(cut -d' ' -f13 <<<"$ONE_LINE")"
    echo "raw = |${RAW_MILLI_SECONDS}|"
    MILLI_SECONDS=${RAW_MILLI_SECONDS/ms/}
    LINE_COUNT=$(( LINE_COUNT + 1 ))
    echo "finished value = .${MILLI_SECONDS}."
    echo "line count = ${LINE_COUNT}"
    FILE_SUM=$(( $MILLI_SECONDS + $FILE_SUM ))
done < logfile.txt
```

output is this:

```
raw = |17607ms|
finished value = .17607.
line count = 1
get_wallet_times.sh: line 14: 17607 + 0 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is " + 0 ")
```

From the output, it sure looks like I have the milliseconds correct. So I do not understand why I get that error (above).

One additional bit of information. I am running this on MacOS, in case that makes any difference in the bash syntax.

Thnx for you help. Please let me know if there is anything else I need to add here.

EDIT:

```
head -1 logfile.txt | od -c
0000000    .   /   t   e   s   t   _   1   _   i   w   s   _   1   .   t
0000020    x   t   :   [ 033   [   3   2   m   i   n   f   o 033   [   3
0000040    9   m   ]       1               -       1   2   -   0   5
0000060    2   2   :   1   8   :   1   3   .   4   3   6       :      \t
0000100  033   [   3   2   m   F   i   n   i   s   h   e   d       c   r
0000120    e   a   t   e   W   a   l   l   e   t   R   a   n   d   o   m
0000140    ,       t   o   t   a   l       t   i   m   e       1   7   6
0000160    0   7   m   s 033   [   3   9   m  \n
0000172
```

Comment: The script runs well here. Are there any CR's in your files?

Comment: or more generally any other invisible characters? Can you add the output of `head -1 logfile.txt | od -c` to the question?

Comment: After modifying one line to `RAW_MILLI_SECONDS="$(<<< "$ONE_LINE" tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f11)"` it works well for me in Lubuntu 18.04.x LTS. Are there invisible characters in the file, that are not transmitted via your snippet in the edited question? MacOS is not linux, and some command may act in a different way from what we (linux users) expect.

Comment: The script posted has 15 lines but the error is being reported in the line number 26.  So, either try the script as posted to find the error or post the full script you are using.

Comment: @Isaac edited output using script above.

Comment: @icarus output of command added to body of question

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak for stack, I made a smaller version of the real script to meet the `minimum reproducible solution`.  I accidentally pasted the results from the real script.   I just reran the `minimum reproducible solution` and updated the results.

Comment: `$RAW_MILLI_SECONDS` contains unprintable characters at the end. They were the the reason `%??` did not work [in this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/555770/108618) and they are the culprit now.

Comment: Using the input and the script you provide, the output of `echo "raw = |${RAW_MILLI_SECONDS@Q}|"` (**note the trailing @Q} becomes `raw = |$'17607ms\E[39m'|` which contains formatting characters.

Comment: One possible solution (without addressing the several special chracter issues) is to use awk: `RAW_MILLI_SECONDS="$(echo "$ONE_LINE" | awk '{print($NF+0)}' )"` but then again, if that works, why not use awk directly?

Comment: The output of `od` shows that there is an escape sequence at the end of the line for an ansi terminal to set the terminal forground color back to the default. replace `MILLI_SECONDS=${RAW_MILLI_SECONDS/ms/}` with `MILLI_SECONDS=${RAW_MILLI_SECONDS%%ms*}` should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without solving the several special character issues:
Awk is able to process the whole file a lot faster:

```
#!/bin/bash
LINE_COUNT=0
FILE_SLOWEST=1
FILE_LONGEST=1

awk '{ val=$NF+0;
       if(NR==1)  {min=val;max=val}
       if(max<val){max=val}
       if(min>val){min=val}
       sum+=val
     } END {
          avg=sum/NR
          print(sum,avg,max,min)
     }' logfile.txt  | {

        read SUM AVG MAX MIN
        echo "The Sum of values           is = $SUM"
        echo "The averaged value of times is = $AVG"
        echo "The maximum of times        is = $MAX"
        echo "The minimum of times        is = $MIN"

    }
```

Understand that to keep the `read` values after the pipe has ended you need something like:

```
read SUM AVG MAX MIN < <(awk ...)
```

Comment: That would work for computing average.  Would I end up with the same problem though when I want to show min/max?  Your solution to use awk on one line (in the comments above) would be the solution I will use.

Comment: Are you saying that the awk script above works with your logfile? If so, awk is perfectly able to calculate max/min/avg and std if needed also. I'll edit to include those.

Comment: yes.  that solves it for me.  thank you :)

Comment: Do that solve your problem? @just_a_programmer

Comment: yes.  thank you.  I am going to have to learn about awk.  very powerful.  much appreciated.